# Batch replace using DXL in Lotus Notes Design elements or turn columns to shared columns?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have a bunch of views that have a bunch of columns that I would like to turn into shared columns.  I have noticed that I can edit the DXL and simply put the  tag around the column.  This works fine for one or two columns in one or two views but I have several columns to change over a couple of dozen views.  I have Team Studio but it seems to be limited on the amount of text that can be but into the find and replace text fields.

Is there an existing utility that would let me turn a regular column into a shared column? Or at least  batch mode change of a large amount of DXL text?   I already figured that I might need to be creative in that I already have some views with shared columns and I would not want to put an extra set of sharedcolumn tags around those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a free tool, [Ytria viewEZ](http://www.ytria.com/website.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_viewEZen?OpenDocument&Lang=en) does this (and more).